# getting the error [NSCFString setBackgroundImage:forState:]: 

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimageview, uiimage, uibutton

i am getting the following error while adding the background image  to the content of a table view cell

```
 [NSCFString setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

    UIButton *playBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            playBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x+playBtnXPos, y+playBtnYPos, playBtnWidth, playBtnHeight); 
            [playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            if(playingButton && streamer){
                if(playingButtonTag == i && [streamer isPlaying]){
                    [playBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pauseBtnimgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    playingButton = playBtn;
                }else [playBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playBtnimgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }else [playBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:playBtnimgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            playBtn.tag = i;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:playBtn];

.....
```

can anybody help me out...

thanks...

Comment: -1. You don't seem to be showing the problematic code. Is the background image. Where else is "playingButton" used?

Comment: Two things: 1)Add some spaces. It's hard to read. Help us help you. 2) Tell us exactly which line it crashes on. Look at your stack trace, and it'll tell you. Again, help us help you.

Comment: its crashing while setting the backgroundimage to the button..

Comment: You have multiple. Multiple. MULTIPLE lines where you use that exact method signature. That doesn't help at all. Again, point out the exact line where it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have memory management issues (selectors being sent to the wrong instances is a sign of memory management issues), there are a number of things you can do:

1. Re-read the Cocoa [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) and make sure that you're following them.
2. Run the [static analyser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/). This will often pick up places where you have neglected the memory management rules.
3. Try using [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW3) to find out whether [and when] you are sending messages to unallocated instances.

Comment: +1 for NSZombiesEnabled, which will tend to make the errors more sensible. However, it would be even more useful if it had retain/release logging (like Instruments does). There's MallocStackLogging, but I don't think that tracks retain/release.

Comment: Selectors being sent to wrong instances are more likely to be a sign of sending it to the wrong object or missing methods. Usually it's EXC_BAD_ACCESS for sending messages to unallocated instances.

Comment: @David Liu: When a selector has been sent to the wrong instance, often it because the original object has been deallocated and another instance of a different class has been allocated in its place (which is a memory management issue).

Comment: Yeah, but in my experience, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is much more likely to happen. Plus, it would require the new instance to be allocated in the exact same place. Sure, it's totally totally possible, but I've never had it happen in practice.

Comment: @David Liu, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is another symptom yes, but it is not unlikely at all for objects to be allocated in place of previously-deallocated objects.

Answer (score -1):

The runtime is saying it all: You're trying to call something in `NSString` that doesn't exist, and I know for sure that `[NSCFString setBackgroundImage:forState:]` does not exist, hence the error and "possibly" a crash. The compiler should show you a warning in your source code where you're going wrong.

Comment: But, as you can see in his code, he doesn't use the `setBackgroundImage:forState:` method on a string, he uses it on what is supposed to be a `UIButton`. Plus, that isn't a compiler error, it is a runtime error,

Comment: i am getting this error in the console while its crashed....-[NSCFString setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c39170
2010-11-23 15:19:17.638 Yes.com[30281:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c39170'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: I know he doesn't. He may have his brackets wrong. He should just run it through the debugger.